# Unexpected result combining 3 URIs

Tags: c#, .net, http, url, uri

I have the following code to concat some URIs:

```
public static Uri BuildUri()
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.60:8080");
    Uri restUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/rest/api/2");
    Uri url = new Uri(restUri, "/mypreferences?key=my.config.value");

    return url;
}
```

I expect the following address, in the result URI:

```
http://192.168.1.60:8080/rest/api/2/mypreferences?key=my.config.value
```

But I'm getting:

```
http://192.168.1.60:8080/mypreferences?key=my.config.value
```

Would someone please could explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.60:8080");
    Uri restUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/rest/api/2/");
    Uri url = new Uri(restUri, "mypreferences?key=my.config.value");

    Console.WriteLine (url);
}
```

This correctly prints

```
http://192.168.1.60:8080/rest/api/2/mypreferences?key=my.config.value
```

The difference must be because of how it interprets the forward slash in different URI's. Where exactly this is mentioned in the docs I haven't found yet, but at least you have your solution already.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ie, you need to change the last url. You are passing the `baseUri` however you should pass the `restUri`:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.60:8080");
Uri restUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/rest/api/2/");
Uri url = new Uri(restUri, "mypreferences?key=my.config.value");   
                   ^^^^^^---Here
```

Comment: Ouch! Silly fault. Thanks

Comment: I've changed what you said and got same results. I'm going to redo the  question again.

Answer (score 1):

You use the baseUri in both creating the restUri and url. You probably meant to do this instead:

```
public static Uri BuildUri()
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.60:8080");
    Uri restUri = new Uri(baseUri, "rest/api/2");
    Uri url = new Uri(restUri, "mypreferences?key=my.config.value");
    return url;
}
```

Use baseUri to create restUri and use restUri to create the final url. Also notice how i have left out the leading slashes in the sub urls. The Uri class will handle the correct concatenation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Related: [Appending multiple segments with System.Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148499/appending-multiple-segments-with-system-uri)

You want to append a / to the end of your path, and remove it from the first path.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri( "http://192.168.1.60:8080" );
Uri restUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/rest/api/2/");
```